# Gradle Android Buildscript Configuration with Flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-play-publisher

I'm working on an Android application that has two different flavours and I'm looking at the [Gradle Play Publisher](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher) to automate the release to the alpha channels by using the Gradle wrapper command line.

Each of the two flavours corresponds to a different developer account on Google Play.

The issue that I'm facing now, is that the Play Publisher plugin only takes one Google Play configuration ( service account + auth key ).

I'm not particularly familiarised with Gradle, but I'm guessing is flexible enough to iterate over the flavours and execute a task with a 'per-flavour' buildscript config.

Does anyone know how can I accomplish this? Maybe examples of other projects that manipulate buildscript configuration based on flavours?

Thanks in advance.

Relevant part of the `build.gradle` script.

```
android {

    ...

    productFlavors {
        flavour1 {
            applicationId 'com.example.1'
        }
        flavour2 {
            applicationId 'com.example.2'
        }
    }
}
...

play {
     serviceAccountEmail = '<SERVICE_ACCOUNT>'
     pk12File = file('<PATH_TO_KEY>')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding two solutions that I found in Github to work around this issue, as no official support for this feature is provided by the project developers.

Solution #1: Using environment variables

https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/issues/65

Solution #2: Using Gradle Task and custom config files

https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/issues/76#issuecomment-121756953

You can follow the complete discussion here:

https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/issues/76